# Error The instruction at "0x00000001" referenced memory at "0x00000001" when using box cox transformation in BiodiversityR package

Tags: package, rstudio, cox-regression, r-commander

I am trying to use the `BiodiversityR` package in `Rcommander` since I need to box-cox transform some data. However, even when trying with the example files, I get this error just after selecting the box cox transformation in the Menu, and `Rcommander` and  `Rstudio` just shut down. What is it?

```
The instruction at "0x00000001" referenced memory at "0x00000001". The memory could not be "read"
```

What could I do?

Comment: Not sure if the following helps or not: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/the-instruction-at-0x00000001-referenced-memory-at/12382c72-d30e-4cbf-ac2e-8d218d3c8bc2?msgId=872e2ee9-a648-4667-a91c-57360bedd399

Comment: Not really but thanks anyway!